# What is Unknown Nullability in C# 8?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

In C# 8.0 we can have nullable reference types. [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullability-of-types) state that there are 4 types of nullability. The first 3 are quite clear but I fail to understand the point of "unknown". The docs say it is used with generics but when I try to call a method on an unconstrained variable of T type in generics it just warns as if the type is nullable. I fail to see the difference between unknown and nullable. Why does unknown exist? How does it manifest itself?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take the following generic method:

```
public static T Get<T>(T value)
{
    return value;
}
```

If we call it like `Get<string>(s)`, the return is non-nullable, and if we do `Get<string?>(s)`, it's nullable.

However if you are calling it with a generic argument like `Get<T>(x)` and `T` isn't resolved, for example it is a generic argument to your generic class like below...

```
class MyClass<T>
{
    void Method(T x)
    {
        var result = Get<T>(x);
        // is result nullable or non-nullable? It depends on T
    }
}
```

Here the compiler does not know if eventually it will be called with a nullable or non-nullable type.

There is a new type constraint we can use to signal that `T` cannot be null:

```
public static T Get<T>(T value) where T: notnull
{
    return value;
}
```

However, where `T` is unconstrained and still open, the nullability is unknown.

If these unknowns were treated as nullable then you could write the following code:

```
class MyClass<T>
{
    void Method(T x)
    {
        var result = Get<T>(x);
        // reassign result to null, cause we we could if unknown was treated as nullable
        result = null;
    }
}
```

In the case where `T` was not nullable, we should have got a warning. So with unknown nullability types, we want warnings when dereferencing, but also warnings for assigning potentially `null`.

Comment: When I do  var result = Test.Get<T>(x); result.ToString(); the compiler complains about dereferencing a possibly null value. I don't see how unknown is different from simply nullable in this case.

Comment: In terms of warnings they behave the same, but they are semantically different. You could say the difference is academic, and if that was your point then I agree.

Comment: I would still like to know why the difference was introduced. It seems strange to introduce such a distinction in the language for academic purposes.

Comment: My bad, just re-read the spec, update the answer, the last part explains it.

Comment: Ah that's more like it